# sharepoint 2019 SQL server setting MAXDOP

Tags: sharepoint-server

Installing sharepoint 2019 in UAT and getting error while running the config wizard which says MAX degree of parallelism should be set to 1 when checked with the DB team it has been set to 4 since there are other application using the same sql server they set it to 4. my question is 1.can we set MAXDOP to 1 particaularly for sharepoint application? 2. can we set MAXDOP to 4 or any other value in between 2-64?

Answer (score 1):

MAXDOP is an instance-wide setting, so it can only be set for SQL, and not for individual databases. This is one reason of several why its good for SharePoint to get its own instance, rather than putting sharepoint on a sql instance that is used for other applications as well.

As a side note, it's interesting how this is listed as a "best practice" in the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/best-practices-for-sql-server-in-a-sharepoint-server-farm), when the reality is that it's a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint utilizes Microsoft SQL Server as a backend. Since SQL Server 2016, every edition of SQL Server supports setting MAXDOP at not just the instance/server level, but the individual database level as well, and yet, even for SharePoint 2019 released years after that, they still recommend crippling the performance of any well-written and modern database applications you host on the same infrastructure by setting MAXDOP to 1 at the instance level.

That's very convenient for Microsoft's strategy- of conning smaller clients who can't justify running separate database servers for their modern applications and SharePoint- into moving to 'SharePoint Online' and giving them more money monthly, so it's unlikely that they will ever correct that advice.

At the instance/server MAXDOP should generally be set to approximately the number of physical cores of your database server, unless you have many, many cores.

By all means, let the SharePoint installer set your instance/server MAXDOP to 1, then immediately afterward, change it back to a normal setting so your normal programs work fine, and then go into every SharePoint database and set the MAXDOP to 1 there instead.